# Dynamic Alert Process

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alert

I am after advice more than I direct answer or if someone has done something similar.  I will try and explain what I want to do.  I am want to create a SQL a stored procedure that checks against table and dynmically runs the code that is situate in one of the fields, something similar to SQL Alerts but I dont want to create lots of alerts.  My table would have something like an Alert Name field and a piece of code that checks to see if an order has been put in a table for over £150 as an example, there will be lots of other similar small pieces of code. This table would be linked to another that dictates how often it runs depending on the time of day then a futher table that says what happens when the alert is triggered, a stage one alert would be an email a stage 2 would be a text.  I then have a stored procedure that runs constantly checking the necessary tables to see if anything needs to be run.  I appreciate this might be a little vague for a direct answer but if anyone could offer some advice that would be much appreciated.

Hi DMason/Others,  sorry I was typing that out a little late last night and yep vagueness seemed to be the order of the day ;) I am trying to put together a custom alert system that uses a Stored procedure to analyse a table to see if an alert is scheduled and then run it.  Right I have a table that contains 2 columns Name and Code, Name is just a piece of text and Code will contain a basic select statement as an example. I then have a table of schedules for the alert this will show day of the week and time e.g. working day or other.  My next table shows Thresholds for example for an alert the threshold might be 2 e.g. the original select statement cant return any more records than 2 otherwise the alert is triggered.  I also have an alert level table, this means that if an alert has only been triggered once in a specific piece of time and alert goes out as an email if it gets triggered again then a text messages is sent out.  There is a final table that contains things like email addresses and mobiles associated with each of the alerts.  I have the design more or less put together in my head but just trying to think of the best way to put it all together or if anyone has done something similar...Hope that gives a little more detail :)

Thanks...P

Comment: I agree it's a little vague :) My initial reaction is this process might be better served by an external application...maybe something running as a service to process/analyze your data and take action accordingly. I suggest offering as many details as you can. There may be some considerably better options.

Comment: Further details added to original question.